# save files in a location of android where mobile user cannot access

Tags: android

How to keep files in a location of android where mobile user can not access. I have used `context.getDir("SystemRecordLog", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` to keep files in phone memory but if there is a internal SD then it will be save files into internal SD and then it can access by mobile user. Please give me a solution for this matter.

Comment: App data lives in `/data/data/com.you.app/` which normal user cannot read. But root user can read. If you absolutely want to protect data, then consider encrypting it.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) "files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user)." This page also shows how to use the internal storage.

Comment: In gingerbread version(Galaxy mini mobile) files saved in application path will not be able to access by the user but  in jelly bean it will saved in internal sd memory and it can access.Please give me a solution.

Comment: But this is what the Android documentation states... Android is an open-source and highly configurable platform. As S.D commented on your question, maybe you need to consider encryption if you are worried the user will go snooping on the device. It's really unpreventable in every case.

Comment: ya krsteeve,I got solution and Its my mistake.firstly I have tried with android 2.3.3 libraries but it wasn't worked in jellybean then I have tried with android 4.2 libraries,then files wasn't accessible to users..,so my problem is ok,thanks krsteeve for your comments....

Answer (score 1):

The unfortunate fact is No matter how hard you try, you can not hide anything from a rooted user.
But for most purposes, device's internal storage should be ok for you. Check this link for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html